Какой знак требуется?
Взгляд меняется на присущий ему: агрессивный и упрямый(?) брови хмурятся у переносицы.
Какой знак следует поставить? Учитывая, что последняя часть предложения "брови хмурятся у переносицы" не относится по смыслу к изменениям взгляда, однако стоит уже после двоеточия. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Можно оформить следующим образом:
(1) Взгляд меняется на присущий ему, агрессивный и упрямый, брови хмурятся у переносицы.
Или так (присоединительная конструкция при подчеркивании оборота):
(2) Взгляд меняется на присущий ему — агрессивный и упрямый, брови хмурятся у переносицы.
Пояснение

Это БСП, связь бессоюзная, обозначена запятой. Оборот агрессивный и упрямый относится к первому предложению, причем его можно рассматривать при одиночном союзе И как цельную конструкцию.

Оборот поясняет сочетание присущий ему (какой именно?) и в общем случае обособляется запятыми.

Для обособления можно использовать тире, но не двоеточие. При этом второй знак перед запятой опускается.

Двоеточие возможно в таком предложении с однородным рядом и обобщающим словосочетанием присущий ему:


Взгляд меняется на присущий ему: агрессивный, упрямый, недоверчивый, брови хмурятся у переносицы.

А в этом предложении: "Взгляд меняется на присущий ему: агрессивный, упрямый, недоверчивый, брови хмурятся у переносицы" перед словом "брови" не должно стоять тире вместо запятой по правилу? Например: "Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире:
Везде: над головой, под ногами и рядом с тобой — живёт, грохочет, торжествуя свои победы, железо".

Здесь действует правило Розенталя, пункт 8   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103     Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается. Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.

"Взгляд меняется на присущий ему — агрессивный и упрямый; брови хмурятся у переносицы," - мне кажется, лучше точку с запятой, чтобы не мешать взгляд и нособровь. Или нет?

Мне нравится ваш вариант: точка с запятой. В этом случае мы делаем увеличенную паузу. Выглядит выразительно. Здесь уже идет "подбор красок", то есть поиск нужной автору интонационной структуры (всё в пределах нормы). Более приглушенные оттенки при постановке запятой: Взгляд меняется на присущий ему, агрессивный и упрямый, брови хмурятся у переносицы. И подчеркнутые  при постановке тире+точка с запятой: Взгляд меняется на присущий ему — агрессивный и упрямый; брови хмурятся у переносицы.  Внимание автора как бы скользит, останавливаясь на отдельных деталях.

Я бы предпочёл вариант без знаков препинания перед словами «агрессивный и упрямый»:
Взгляд меняется на присущий ему агрессивный и упрямый, брови хмурятся у переносицы.

хочется спросить: агрессивный и упрямый - что, меняется на что?

@Буратино:  «хочется спросить: агрессивный и упрямый - что, меняется на что?» ===  К сожалению, Ваш вопрос мне непонятен…

Взгляд меняется на агрессивный, - считаешь, правильно согласовано? До этого быть "взгляд", а поменялся на "агрессивный". Тепло меняется на мягкое.

@Буратино: «Взгляд меняется на агрессивный, - считаешь, правильно согласовано? До этого быть "взгляд", а поменялся на "агрессивный". Тепло меняется на мягкое». === По-моему, вариант без запятой не более неправилен, чем вариант с запятой, который так нравится Вам. Я имею в виду этот вариант: «Взгляд меняется на присущий ему, агрессивный и упрямый…»

Запятая отменяет необходимость согласования, наверное, может быть уточнением.
